# Extension of field automorphisms

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, automorphism-group

In the case of finite extension of finite field extension it's easy to see that every automorpshim can be extended in a "good" way. Now, my question is :
Is it possible also in the case of infinite extensions?

Comment: Can you precise what a "good" way is?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net for example if i have $K \subset L \subset M$ if i Take an automorphism of L fixing K can i extend it to an automorphism of M which fixes K?

Comment: For example, it's straightforward to show that $\mathbb R$ has only the trivial automorphism, so no nontrivial automorphisms of real algebraic extensions of $\mathbb Q$ extend to $\mathbb R$.